# CodeEffects: Load RuleEditor On button Click

Tags: codeeffects

Is it possible to load different partial views in my Index.cshtml that contains the CodeEffect().RuleEditor().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The rule editor of Code Effects engine is a plain client class. It can be used as any other js component. Do you have a particular issue with your project or you are asking how to code partial views?